# Sum values by same date and hour from table in R Studio

Tags: r

I have a table showing date, hour, minutes, seconds, rainfall.mm

Now I want to sum all the rainfall.mm within the same date and hour.

The table looks like this:

```
      Date        Hour Minutes Seconds Rainfall.mm.
      25/05/2009   12      43      34          0.2
      26/05/2009   12      20      48          0.2
      26/05/2009   12      29      44          0.2
      26/05/2009   12      46      27          0.2
      26/05/2009   13       2      41          0.2
      26/05/2009   13      15      27          0.2
      26/05/2009   13      25      48          0.2
      26/05/2009   14      46      25          0.2
      26/05/2009   14      59       0          0.2
      26/05/2009   15       8      50          0.2
```

What I would like to end up with is a table in where the rainfall is summed by the same date and same hour like this:

```
      Date        Hour Minutes Seconds Rainfall.mm.
      25/05/2009   12      43      34          0.2
      26/05/2009   12      20      48          0.6
      26/05/2009   13       2      41          0.6
      26/05/2009   14      46      25          0.4
      26/05/2009   15       8      50          0.2
```

It does not really matter what the Minutes and Seconds look like.

I have no idea how to do this, I tried several things but I am still new in R Studio and can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to keep the `Minutes` and `Seconds` columns, then just use a `group_by()` and `summarise()` like this.

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Date, Hour) %>% 
  summarise(Rainfall = sum(Rainfall.mm.))
```

However, if you want to keep the other columns you can use another measure instead of the `sum()` inside `summarise()`. In this case I would use `first()` to pick the first value in each group.

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Date, Hour) %>% 
  summarise(Rainfall = sum(Rainfall.mm.), 
            Minutes = first(Minutes), 
            Seconds = first(Seconds))
```